# How to find a String based on Date in vi editor "Feb 12, 2014 1:00:53 PM"

Tags: full-text-search, vi

My Date Stamp in Catalina.out log file is based on format "Feb 12, 2014 1:00:53 PM", i wanted to search exception occurred on the specified time, how can i find that in Vi editor??? my log files are very large containing size in GB's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found a way and it worked, hope fully it will help others.

in my case vi simple search recognized space and , and - issue is only with : or / so to search Feb 12, 2014 1:00:53 PM use /Feb 12, 2014 1\:00\:53 PM

before writing : or / in search just type \ before it.

Comment: @JKirchartz: yes you are putting \ will ignore the character in search and in my case its working... thanks.

Answer (score 2):

to search in vim use the `/` command - type `/Feb 12, 2014 1:00:53 PM` and hit enter - all matches should get highlighted. Use `n` to move to the next occurrence and `N` to move to the previous occurrence.

**edit**:

Putting `\` in front of a character will escape it so it can be used in your search - if you were trying to search and replace "http://" with "https://" you could search like `:s/http:\/\//https\/\//gi` - which would keep the `/`'s from ending your regex statement - alternatively you can use a different character to avoid the picket fences (`\/\//\/\`) like `:s#http://#https://#gi`

Comment: JKirchartz thanks for reply, but its not that simple. simple search wont recognized the symbol like space, : or Slash...

Comment: Oh yeah - I forgot about the escape character.